# How to render data on web page while using Markdown

Tags: php, mysql, markdown

I created a page for uploading question using Markdown and when they complete the form and submit it, I save the form in database(MYSQL) which includes question and there is some HTML and Javascript code in it, and when I tried to render it on web page to show the question it looks like this, it looks like string but I want the out like StackOverflow does.

[image: Output that it is showing]

Comment: Maybe https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php ?

Comment: Perhaps take a look at the HTML that is written, not how it's rendered, for clues. I would agree that your database output needs to be html_entity_decode'd